# Add line to a file with value from environment variable

Tags: ansible

I'd like to add line to the end of a file `filename` with value: `Path is X` where `X` is value of environment variable `$PATH`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new task like this one:

```
- name: Put path in file
  lineinfile:
    dest: /path/to/file.txt
    create: yes
    line: "Path is {{ lookup('env', 'PATH') }}"
    state: present
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically the following task will do:

```
- name: Ensure the file contains 'Path is $PATH' line
  lineinfile:
    dest: your_file
    insertafter: EOF
    regexp: "^Path is"
    line: "Path is {{ ansible_env.PATH }}"
```

But remember:

- the resulting line will contain value for the user used to run Ansible tasks on the target machine built for the non-interactive shell. For example on OS X, by default, it won't include the paths sourced from `/etc/paths` or `/etc/paths.d`, nor will it contain the value of `PATH` which is set (altered) in `.bash_profile`.
- using `lineinfile` module will not add the line to the end of the file, if a line beginning with `Path is` is already present elsewhere (not at the end of the file) in the destination file, it will replace its value.